# Post compiled php 5.4 curl installation

Tags: php, linux, curl, installation, centos

I recently compiled php 5.4 from source. I have Centos 6. I used this configuration:

```
# ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql
# make
# make install
# cp php.ini-dist /usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

I realize now that I do not have cURL installed. I don't know how to install cURL after a compiled installation of php. Using `yum install php-curl` installs cURL for php 5.3. I tried this already with an apache restart and it did not show up on my phpinfo file.

How do I install cURL under these circumstances?

Comment: is that really my only option?

Answer (score 0):

If you would have installed php using:

```
yum install php
```

Then could would add curl to php via:

```
yum install php-curl
```

However since you compiled php from source, you'll have to re-compile php and add the --with-curl flag.

You're probably best to just have yum install and update php for you unless there was a specific reason you wanted to compile it from source.